Social login using web3 in flutter
I am trying to get user information after web3 authentication using
Web3AuthResponse response = await Web3AuthFlutter.login(
LoginParams(loginProvider: Provider.google,extraLoginOptions: ExtraLoginOptions( ) ));
but a persistent loader is showing and not giving any response after taking the google email
web3Auth_flutter package
